# Angular/Typescript Text with routerLink

Tags: html, angular, typescript, innerhtml, angular-router

**Updated Question for more Clarity**:

Need to display some texts and links as innerHTML(data from service/DB) in the Angular HTML and when user clicks, it should go to ***Typescript*** and programmatically navigates by `router.navigate`

Also, How to add DomSanitizer from @ViewChild/ElementRef

Added all example in below code

[Here is the updated stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxg9cj?file=src%2Fapp%2Finnerhtmltest%2Finnerhtmltest.component.html)

As shown in screenshot from angular.io some texts and some links

[image]

Comment: any particular reason for not having any router module/routes defined?

Comment: also you can't do html content like this, you have to sanitzer or mark it safe.

https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Comment: @alejendro Camba :Modules/router define is secondary.If we can navigate to goto(), i can achieve the goal.

Comment: @E. Maggni. Please take a look at the screen shot in the question. I want to achieve like the some texts and some links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't realize you answered my comment. Angular routing is not secondary, if you don't use Angular modules you'll end up with just an HTML/CSS/Typescript application. you need at least the RouterModule for Angular to be able to use routing and hence, do what it's supposed to with the DOM.

First:

- You are not importing RouterModule

  solution:

  ```
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot([])  // this one
  ]
  ```

Second:

- You can't bind Angular events through innerHTML property

  fix:

Make use of `@ViewChild` directive to change your `innerHTML` property and manually bind to the `click` event, so change in your `app.component.html` from

```
<div id="box" [innerHTML]="shouldbedivcontent" ></div>
```

to

```
<div #box id="box"></div>
```

Now, in your `app.component.ts`, add a property to hold a reference to that "box" element so you can later make some changes to the *dom* with it:

```
  @ViewChild('box')  container: ElementRef;
```

Implement AfterViewInit, that hook is where you will be able to actually handle your container, if you try using it for example in OnInit you'd get undefined because that component's html is not in the dom yet.

```
export class AppComponent  implements AfterViewInit {
```

and

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.container.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.shouldbedivcontent;
    this.container.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', 
      () => this.goto('bar')
    );
}
```

change `shouldbedivcontent` property from:

```
'1) this is a click 
 <a (click)="goto("bar")">Click</a><br> 
 2)this is with routerlink 
 <a routerLink="" (click)="goto("bar")">Click</a><br> 
 3)This only works with href 
 <a href="goto/bar" title="bar">bar</a>&nbsp; and test'
```

to

```
'1) this is a click 
 <a id="link_1">Click</a><br> 
 2)this is with routerlink 
 <a [routerLink]="" (click)="goto(\'bar\')">Click</a><br> 
 3)This only works with href 
 <a href="goto/bar" title="bar">bar</a>&nbsp; and test'
```

And even so you'd still not get the default anchor style unless you apply some styling yourself.

**Third**

You are not *HTML sanitizing*, which could be dangerous. [read more here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

**MY SUGGESTION:**

Seems like a lot to do for you and a lot to read for someone else working alongside you for something you could easily do like in the example below!

Move your html to your `app.component.html`:

```
<div id="box">
  1) this is a click 
  <a (click)="goto('bar')">Click</a><br> 
  2)this is with routerlink 
  <a routerLink="" (click)="goto('bar')">Click</a><br> 
  3)This only works with href 
  <a href="goto/bar" title="bar">bar</a>&nbsp; and test
</div>

<p>Below is actual content</p>
```

You'll notice that everything works now, except the anchor without routerLink or href, because that's not a link.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the new stackblitz, i suggest a change of approach, binding to innerHTML is ok when working with plain text or even some simple html but not a great choice to bind events or routing logic.

Angular's Renderer2 provides with a bunch of methods to dyncamically add elements to the DOM. With that on the table, you just need a little effort to take that simple html you get from your backend and turn it into something like (paste this property in your code to test it along the rest of the code provided below):

```
public jsonHTML = [
  {
    tagName: '',
    text: 'some text with click ',
    attributes: {
    }
  },
  {
    tagName: 'a',
    text: 'bar',
    attributes: {
      value: 'bar' // goto parameter
    }
  },
  {
    tagName: '',
    text: ' some more text with click ',
    attributes: {
    }
  },
  {
    tagName: 'a',
    text: 'foo',
    attributes: {
      value: 'foo' // goto parameter
    }
  }
]
```

Once you have it, it's  way easier to create all of those elements dynamically:

this is for the code in your Q1:

Inject Renderer2 with `private r2: Renderer2`

And replace the Q1 related code in AfterViewInit hook to:

```
const parent = this.r2.createElement('div');  // container div to our stuff

this.jsonHTML.forEach((element) => {
  const attributes = Object.keys(element.attributes);
  const el = element.tagName && this.r2.createElement(element.tagName);
  const text = this.r2.createText(element.text);

  if (!el) {  // when there's no tag to create we just create text directly into the div.
    this.r2.appendChild(
      parent,
      text
    );
  } else { // otherwise we create it inside <a></a>
    this.r2.appendChild(
      el,
      text
    );

    this.r2.appendChild(
      parent,
      el
    );
  }
  
  if (attributes.length > 0) {
    attributes.forEach((name) => {
      if (el) {
        this.r2.setAttribute(el, name, element.attributes[name]); // just the value attribute for now

       if (name === 'value') { 
          this.r2.listen(el, 'click', () => {
            this.goto(element.attributes[name]); // event binding with property "value" as parameter to navigate to
          })
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('no html tag specified as element...');
      }
    })
  }
})

this.r2.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, parent); // div added to the DOM
```

No html sanitizer needed and no need to use routerLink either just inject Router and navigate to the route you want! Make improvements to the code t make it fit your needs, it should be at least a good starting point

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro Camba.I have used ViewChild and routing in my working copy,  but the stackbliz didnt add for the simplicty. Your solution will not work if we use innerHTML.my content will come from a Service/DB. I have tried HTML Sanatizer, but I am missing something while using Sanatizer.If you can help me there that would be great.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Remember that event bindings won’t work with innerHTML, you have to manually bind events after you get your html content and set it to your innerHTML. See the code where says ngAfterViewInit

Comment: hi @Alejandro Camba I have created another stackbliz for more clarity 
 please take a look  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxg9cj?file=src%2Fapp%2Finnerhtmltest%2Finnerhtmltest.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a css problem.

1. `<a href="something"></a>` looks like a link
2. `<a [routerLink]="something"></a>` looks like a link, because if you inspect the HTML it actually gets an `href` property added because of `routerLink`
3. `<a (click)="goTo()"></a>` does NOT look like a link, because there is no `href`

Chrome and Safari default user agents css will not style `<a>` without an `href` (haven't confirmed Firefox but I'm sure its likely).  Same thing for frameworks like bootstrap.

Updated stackblitz with CSS moved to global, not app.css
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkgmkc?embed=1&file=src/styles.css

This will style all links as the default blue, or -webkit-link if that browser supports it.  It should be in your global.css file if you want it to work through the whole app.

```css
a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
  color: -webkit-link;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: thank you @cjd82187.but this doesn't work when we use innerHTML.Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gynf1a

Comment: Thats because the CSS was in app.css which scopes it to a particular component.  Inner HTML wasn't picking that up.  I moved it to the global styles CSS in a new stackblitz.  Again, all of this came down a CSS issue.  If you inspect element you can see what is getting applied and why/why not for others.

Comment: Oh, I've seen you updated your original question that you need the click events to happen in innerHTML too, not just the styling.  I can try do look into that later tonight, don't have the time now.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly for me :D

```
 @Directive({
  selector: "[linkify]",
})

// * Apply Angular Routing behavior, PreventDefault behavior
export class CustomLinkDirective {
  @Input()
  appStyle: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private ref: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    href && this.router.navigate([href]);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.ref.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((a: HTMLElement) => {
        const href = a.getAttribute("href");
        href &&
          this.appStyle &&
          a.classList.add("text-indigo-600", "hover:text-indigo-500");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

HOW I USE IT

```
 <p linkify
     class="mt-3 text-lg text-gray-500 include-link"
     [innerHtml]="apiSectionText"
   ></p>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br8Mo.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).